# Performance de call_user_func_array . Por que as bibliotecas usam-o apenas com 5 argumentos ou mais?

Tags: php

Vamos à discussão: Esses dias atrás dei uma olhada no código-fonte de uma classe do ZendFramework2. Lá havia uma implementação do método mágico `__call`. Nesse método existia algo que me chamou atenção: A utilização de `call_user_func_array` foi restrita apenas quando o método que se intenta chamar tinha mais de 4 argumentos. Juntamente havia um comentário em inglês, que esqueci qual é, que explica o por quê disso.

Para confirmar que isso não era nenhuma neura minha (nem do ZendFramework), eu fui dar uma olhada no código-fonte do `Laravel4` e me deparei com a mesma coisa (porém sem o comentário especificando o  por que).

Veja o trecho do código:

```
public static function __callStatic($method, $args)
    {
        $instance = static::getFacadeRoot();
        if (! $instance) {
            throw new RuntimeException('A facade root has not been set.');
        }
        switch (count($args)) {
            case 0:
                return $instance->$method();
            case 1:
                return $instance->$method($args[0]);
            case 2:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1]);
            case 3:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2]);
            case 4:
                return $instance->$method($args[0], $args[1], $args[2], $args[3]);
            default:
                return call_user_func_array([$instance, $method], $args);
        }
    }
```

Perceba que o `Laravel` só considera utilizar `call_user_func_array` caso  a chamada de `__callStatic` possua a passagem de 5 ou mais argumentos.

Interessante disso é que pessoalmente consideraria isso digitação inútil de código, já que o `call_user_func_array` tornaria a chamada de um método ou função muito mais dinâmica, mas duas bibliotecas conhecidas fizeram justamente da forma que parecia mais complexa.

Então, gostaria de saber qual é o motivo disso.

Existe algum problema em perda de performa (a nível significativo) que induza os frameworks a agirem dessa forma?

Existe algum apontamento do próprio PHP que indique isso?

**Nota**: Quem quiser conferir o código, veja aqui:
https://github.com/illuminate/support/blob/master/Facades/Facade.php

Comment: Sem qualquer análise aprofundada eu começaria por dizer que essa função itera o método da primeira array várias vezes com os diferentes valores existentes na segunda array, ou seja, mapeia as variáveis especificadas no segundo membro, no método especificado no primeiro membro. Imagina ter de mapear valores sem que haja necessidade. Talvez seja essa a ideia geral. Do mesmo jeito que disseste que é uma **digitação inútil**, calcular o total de argumentos, e passar essas referências sem fazer o uso do `user_func_array`, o mesmo seria dizer para o script mapear 2 parâmetros usando essa função.

Comment: Ainda mais, sendo que frameworks são projectados para operar como aplicações de pequeno e grande porte, diminuir o tempo que o script leva a executar um comando e a gerar a resposta é crucial sempre que possível.

Comment: Uma nova informação: A função `call_user_func_array` é 15 vezes mais lenta do que uma chamada comum de uma função. Se isso for chamado muitas vezes (igual no caso do laravel que usa essa classe Facade quase em toda aplicação) poderia ser ruim

Comment: Exacto, como disse acima, imagina ter de mapear 2 valores e levar mais tempo do que o necessário quando podes fazê-lo directamente no método pretendido. Agora, com cerca de 5 argumentos ou mais, o tempo de resposta seria idêntico ou mesmo menor do que passa-los directamente no próprio método. Porém não terias de escrever condições para cada um.

Answer (score 1):

Respondendo a sua pergunta. Sim é mais lento.

Essa [pergunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15057573/alternative-to-call-user-func-array) similar a sua no Stackoverflow gringo  tem como um das respostas que a chamada é 15 vezes mais lenta usando `call_user_func_array` mas **não** põe referências de como chegou a esse número.

Continuei buscando resposta até que achei esse [post](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/182) que realmente faz uma analise a respeito da velocidade das chamadas direta ou utilizando essa função.

Ele chega a conclusão que `call_user_func` é duas vezes mais lenta e `call_user_func_array` é 10%-20% mais lenta que `call_user_func`.

Não encontrei nenhuma informação oficial do PHP. No entanto, lembre-se que quem está por trás do PHP e ZendFramework é a mesma organização a Zend, logo se eles utilizam este código não é digitação inútil.